# Balance check in MatchThem package in R

Tags: r, missing-data, propensity-score-matching

I am conducting inverse probability of treatment weighting (IPTW) with missing data using MatchThem in R. After generating weighted datasets which come from multiple imputed datasets (e.g., m=5), I did balance-checking on confounding variables using bal.tab(data, stats=c('m','ks'), imp.fun='max'). The results only showed the balance after weighting.

I wanted to check the balance before weighting as well, and compare it before and after weighting (like before and after balance checks in Twang or WeightIt).

Could anyone please guide me how I can do the balance check on confounding variables for both unweighted and weighted datasets in MatchThem?

Answer (score 1):

If you've already estimated weights, just set `un = TRUE` in the call to `bal.tab()`. If you want to assess balance before estimating weights, you would supply the PS model formula (e.g., `treat ~ x1 + x2`) to `bal.tab()` and supply the `mids` object (the output of the call to `mice()`) to the `data` argument. This is explained in the `cobalt` documentation, so please read that carefully.